# Heroku how install/upload app

Tags: facebook, command-line, heroku, cloud

How I can upload my files to Heroku? I get a free MB to build a Facebook app, but its tutorial is very hard to understand for a beginner like myself.

I stopped on `$ git commit -am "changed greeting"`.

I created the folder and added the file `c/pc/herokuname123/view/index.ejs`. When I write `$ git commit -am "changed greeting"` there is an error...

Can someone send me a step by step tutorial or something?

I am creating a multiplayer game on Facebook so I want to use Heroku cloud and it's command line gitbush.

I tried to follow this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless something on Heroku has changed, and I do not believe any changes have been implemented, you cannot upload files to Heroku apps.

I use an S3 bucket(s) in order to store uploaded files for my app(s) on Heroku, which happen to be Rails apps. The Heroku file system, other than the temp directory, is write-only.

Perhaps that is different with their Facebook Cloud Services Integration tech. I looked through the document mentioned in your post and did not find anything that would indicate the file storage abilities had changed.

Comment: how to start my app working... i have all files but how to start to work on facebook

Comment: Sorry, do you mean pushing your git repository to Heroku or uploading files. Perhaps I misread your post. And if it's a git push problem, please post the error you mention

Comment: i follow this tutorial: :https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook but stop on git change commit

Comment: Ok. Did you install git (I'm sure you did but want to clarify :) )?

Comment: I figured :). Try these two steps in the tutorial after you make a change to one of the files. 1. git add . (that will add all changed files to the repository). 2. git commit -m'some commit message' (this will make the commit to the local repository. One thing that we do need to clarify is that you have initialized a local git repo (i.e., did you do the step in the tutorial where you fetched the app source code (i.e., git clone etc...)?